# Unlimited contact tables based on producttype

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to create a table structure such that an unlimited number of contacts could be created?

Table 1:
contains 2 products (one product has unlimited number of customer names and contact info)

Table 2:
contains customer contact information

I need to create a view that shows customer contact information and customer contact information. There will be an unlimited number of customer records associated with one of the products.

Need to figure out the schemas at a high level.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you need a many-to-many relationship table that will hold the product primary key and the related customer info primary key.

This will allow you the desired relationship of "many customers can have many products":

**Products table**

```
productid    productname
1            Foo
2            Bar
3            Baz
4            Zop
```

**Customers table**

```
customerid   lastname
1            Smith
2            Jones
3            Miller
```

**CustomerProducts table**

```
customerid   productid
1            1
1            2
2            3
2            2
```

Sample show customer "Smith" having products "Foo" and "Bar" and customer "Jones" having product "Baz" and "Bar".

Typically, this CustomerProducts relationship table will contain more information related to the relationship like for example a purchase date or a quantity (10 Foo bought 2020-06-03) and also have a primary key that can be referenced by an Invoice table to allow listing all products invoiced to a customer.